# How to print ⎓ on ZPL (zebra printer language) Unicode utf-8

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii, bartender

i need to print ⎓ logo on Zebra Printer using ZPL (zebra programming language), can anybody tell me how to print the ⎓ symbol?

i already using code that use UTF-8 code, but it only work with 2 byte of hexadecimal, ⎓ has 3 hex data

```
^XA

^CI28
^FO60,75
^ASN,36,20^FH^FD_c3_ba^FS

^XZ
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `but it only work with 2 byte of hexadecimal` - this is not what the manual says. The manual says *There must be a minimum of two characters designated to follow the underscore*, where the "character" is one hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Hi GSerg,
so i can't print 3 hexadecimal on ZPL? 
because it says only support 2 byte hexadecimal?

Comment: It does not say it supports two bytes. It says it requires at least two characters after `_`. `c3` is two characters, `c` and `3`. Have you actually read the manual? There is even sample code there.

Answer (score 1):

The utf-8 sequence for U+2393 is 0xE2 0x8E 0x93.  Using your example, you would encode that as:

```
^ASN,36,20^FH^FD_e2_8e_93^FS
```

This assumes the font you have mapped to `S` supports that code point.

Comment: Hi, Mark, i already try use ^CI28 and print that code

^XA
^CI28
^ASN,36,20^FH^FD_e2_8e_93^FS
^XZ

but it print a blank page ( i try ot on labelary.com )

Comment: @JASONALBERTSOEGIHARTO That would mean the font does not support it. Consult "Exercise 7 • Asian and Unicode Encodings" from the manual that shows how to select a font that supports the characters. If your font does not support the characters, also see `~DU`.